# asp.net all errors return 404

Tags: c#, iis

I have created an asp.net application that works when I debug in visual strudio. When I run the application on the production server almost everything works, but ANY exception or error returns a 404 page instead of 500, so I can't debug errors.

The httperror log says no errors has occured. This all worked before the last version update.

web.config file:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\SHMSWeb.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
        </system.webServer>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
                <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            </httpErrors>
            <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off" />
            <compilation debug="true" />
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First guess... have you defined a custom error page? And does that page exist?

Comment: haven't defined an error page and don't think I have custom errors enabled

Comment: I have updated with my web.config file

Comment: Could you please post your asp.net core startup.cs codes? It seems that you have defined a custom error page but it is not existed or the path isn't right when the application wants to redirect to that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing .net Framework then check if you have `web.config` file. There should be a section `customErrors` which is probably looking something like this

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="your404page"></customErrors>
```

The mode dictates what'll happen on error. You have the options `RemoteOnly`, `On` and `Off`. Most like you're having RemoteOnly turned on which means locally you'll receive your error messages but on the remote server the error is hidden behind a custom error page (you don't want to show users your errors).

To turn on the error messages on the production server then you'll have to set the value to `Off` (watch out, it's case sensitive!)

Comment: I have tried multiple different configuratuins in the web.config file. update in my post